# Custom view with UIcontrols elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have created a custom view class which is a subclass of UIview class

```
 @interface CustomViewController : UIView
```

and i am using drawRect method to display the contents of the custom view

```
-(void) drawRect(CGRect) rect {

}
```

I am able to display only strings on custom view but i want to add UITextField and UILabelField and UIButton on the custom view how can i do this. Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put your controls in `init...` method of your custom view.

**EDIT**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{    
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
       messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, innerView.frame.size.width-20, 100);
       messageLabel = [messageLabel getSize:messageText FontName:@"Helvetica" FontSize:16 label:messageLabel];
       messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       messageLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
       messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, innerView.frame.size.width-20,messageLabel.frame.size.height );
       [self addSubview:messageLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: which method initWithFrame method you are saying

Comment: but how should i add it to the custom view i am using drawRect method to display the fields

Comment: Its fine but how can i handle the keyboard to hide when i clicked on textfield

Comment: textFieldShouldReturn method is not allowed to use there

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say " textFieldShouldReturn method is not allowed to use there " ???

Comment: i mean to say when i clicked over the textfield keyboard is displayed there then what method should i use there to hide keyboard

Comment: you need to conform protocol in your uiview (in .h file) like @interface yourView : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>  and then set delegate to self like : yourTextField.delegate = self ; and implement the this method :- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
return YES;
}